# Antisymmetric matrices over commutative rings.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with an identity, and let $A$ be a invertible and antisymmetric matrix over $R$ of order $n$. Then how to show there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}AP$ has the form
$\begin{pmatrix} 0& I \\ -I&0 \end{pmatrix}$?

I can do induction to prove it if $R$ is a field. But how to prove it in the general case?

Comment: Is this a known result or a conjecture?

Comment: @user1551 Well, it's an exercise in Wedhorn's book Algebraic Geometry. I just translated its language of schemes to this version.

Comment: Where does your Ring based proof break when you mimic the field case?  The devil is in the details but it seems to me it runs similarly except with rings one e.g. should constantly use determinants to justify things along the way.

Comment: @user8675309 For the proof in the case of field I can use the element in (2,1) to cancel other elements in the first column, and use the element in (1,2) to cancel the first row and so on... After these operations, we will get the result easily. But in commutative rings I cannot do the cancellation.

Comment: @user8675309 The intersection of the second row and the first column.

Comment: The usual field-based proofs should work in Euclidean domains, but a lot of things break down over a general commutative ring, e.g. the principal minor theorem fails, and nonsingular matrices are no longer necessarily invertible. I think it is possible to show that $P^TAP=\pmatrix{0&D\\ -D&0}$ for some *nonsingular* matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$, but I am not sure if one can make $P$ invertible and make $D=I$.